# Conexion de SQL SERVER 2012 con Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

Hola a todos estoy elaborando un sistema con CI , Mysql y Sql Server 2012,
estoy configurando en php 5.6.30 y e puesto todas las exenciones en php.ini y nada me sale este error cuando lo levanto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y eso esta en mi databse,php

```
$db['sqlserver'] = array(
'dsn' => '',
'hostname' => '10.5.50.28',
'username' => 'sa',
'password' => 'SQLserver2012',
'database' => 'BD_UGEL_IMAGING',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

y esto es mi modal

```
class caja_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->db_caja = $this->load->database('caja', TRUE);
    $this->db_resoluciones = $this->load->database('resoluciones', TRUE);
    $this->db_sqlserver = $this->load->database('sqlserver', TRUE);
}
```

Lo curioso esque el maquina de mi compañero si levanta

Comment: Aquí te dejo un post que explica como conectar codeigniter con mysql server [Link del Post](http://system-arts.blogspot.mx/2013/06/como-configurar-codeigniter-para.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo perdí mas de un día con ese problema y al final resulto que mi Windows 7 no estaba completo le faltaba el "Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server®" una vez instalado se quito el mensaje de error que te sale.

Deja las configuraciones como están por que están bien. 
Instala el pack y listo pulsa F5 o recarga la pagina y maravilla todo funciona.

el link de descarga es:

https://www.microsoft.com/es-mx/download/details.aspx?id=36434

aun que creo que posiblemente cambie, pon el google "Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server".

ojo esto es en forma local o en Servidor propio. en hosting compartido no se como vaya a funcionar.

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

parece ser que php a cambiado algunas cosas en las ultimas versiones por temas de seguridad.

de momento me encuentro igual que tu y lo que uso es lo que explican en este video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJG8ipG3Kdo

Comment: Hola yo lo arregle usando extensiones no oficiales sino de comunidades y ahora me corre en mi servidor al 100 si deseas te puedo brindar a mi me sirvio